# Is three months too short of a time to switch companies?

Tags: communication, new-job, company-culture

I've worked at my new company for 3 months now and so far it's been a complete disaster. It's a software company and I was a developer there (first out of school). My biggest complaint being lack of actual training. I got basically no hands on training (with their proprietary software) and it was basically sitting in a meeting discussing database structures. The manager never gives feedback or if there's an issue, I'm never notified about them. I was basically going in blind with no actual training. Couple of months later, he schedules a meeting with me saying I wasn't learning fast enough.

apparently my co-workers have been telling him I'm asking too many questions (this is a VERY non confrontation company) meaning no one tells you any information about what you are doing wrong/right etc..Manager is very shy and introverted so he never really says anything to you until you schedule a meeting.

Comment: OK, so you don't like your situation. That's bad. Do you have a question? I know there is a question in the title, but you might  want to elaborate on it in the question body.

Comment: "Is 3 months too short to leave a job?" I am afraid that is something you will have to decide for yourself. Different people have different levels of tolerance for bad situations, such as yours. If the situation is absolutely intolerable for you, 3 months is even too *long* to leave. (Sticking around just to avoid being called a job hopper may not be worth bearing the stress for another year or two.) If you can tough it out for a bit, maybe the answer would vary.

Comment: First job? Just start looking for a better one now.

Answer (score 0):

You can move jobs if you wish, but companies are not likely to look at it positively. They are likely to ask hard questions like:

- Did you do your best to succeed in the job
- What if you had an issue that you found difficult in this company. Would your first response be to find another job?

On another note, it is not necessary that the next job you find will be better than this one.

Also, structured training is something that most people fresh out of college do expect. In the real world, it is often a luxury. You may get stuck with a number of projects for which goals / objectives are not clearly defined. If you are working for a client, often the client himself does not know what he wants.

Hence, before looking for a new job try asking yourself if you have done the best you can in this company. Try training yourself as much as you can. Try making friends with people around you - and asking them how to improve on things. Get stuff from the grapevine. Often non-formal routes work best.

Also, if you feel like, you could have a meeting with the manager, asking him where best you can learn the things you need to know to get your job done.

Comment: In 40 years in the workplace, I have only had structured training in one and never for a development job. Training on a job is a very unrealistic expectation in my experience. You need to learn how to get up to speed quickly on your own.